# JAVA: highest sum and number of specific num digits in arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I want to draw two arrays, check in which array has the **highest sum of all numbers** and **write how many one-, two- and three-digit numbers are in each array**. Drawing arrays is working but i can't get the later parts of this working.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {
    static int[][] tab_1 = new int[10][10];
    static int[][] tab_2 = new int[10][10];
    static int[][] tab_wyniki = new int[10][10];
    static int[][] tab_1_sum = new int[10][10];
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        wypelnij_tablice(1000);
        wyswietl_tablice_1();
        wyswietl_tablice_2();
        sumuj_tablice();
        wyswietl_sume_tabli();
        suma_tabeli_1();
        wys_sum_tab_1();
    }

    static void wypelnij_tablice(int zakres) {
        Random r = new Random();
        for (int wiersz = 0; wiersz < 10; wiersz++) {
            for (int kolumna = 0; kolumna < 10; kolumna++) {
                tab_1[wiersz][kolumna] = r.nextInt(zakres);
                tab_2[wiersz][kolumna] = r.nextInt(zakres);
            }
        }
    }

    static void wyswietl_tablice_1() {
        System.out.println("tablica pierwsza");
        for (int wiersz = 0; wiersz < 10; wiersz++) {
            for (int kolumna = 0; kolumna < 10; kolumna++) {
                System.out.print(tab_1[wiersz][kolumna] + " , ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    static void wyswietl_tablice_2() {
        System.out.println("tablica druga");
        for (int wiersz = 0; wiersz < 10; wiersz++) {
            for (int kolumna = 0; kolumna < 10; kolumna++) {
                System.out.print(tab_2[wiersz][kolumna] + " , ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    static void sumuj_tablice() {
        for (int wiersz = 0; wiersz < 10; wiersz++) {
            for (int kolumna = 0; kolumna < 10; kolumna++) {
                tab_wyniki[wiersz][kolumna] = tab_1[wiersz][kolumna] + tab_2[wiersz][kolumna];
            }
        }
    }

    static void wyswietl_sume_tabli() {
        System.out.println("suma tablic");
        for (int wiersz = 0; wiersz < 10; wiersz++) {
            for (int kolumna = 0; kolumna < 10; kolumna++) {
                System.out.print(tab_wyniki[wiersz][kolumna] + " , ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    static void suma_tabeli_1() {
        for (int wiersz = 0; wiersz < 10; wiersz++) {
            for (int kolumna = 0; kolumna < 10; kolumna++) {
                tab_1_sum[wiersz][kolumna] = tab_1[wiersz][kolumna];
            }
        }
    }
    
    static void wys_sum_tab_1() {
        System.out.println("suma tabeli 1");
        for (int wiersz = 0; wiersz < 10; wiersz++) {
            for (int kolumna = 0; kolumna < 10; kolumna++) {
                System.out.print(tab_1_sum[wiersz][kolumna] + " , ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am polish and can understand names of your methods, but I suggest to write them in english when you are asking something here. Also you asked for arrays and in your code there are 2-dimensions arrays instead.Your code needs a lot of changes too. First of all, if you want to do it similar to this way which is now, you should create method sum_elements_in_table and as argument in that method there should be int[][] type with table as name. Do not create three methods when you have three tables. What if someone would require from you calculating sum of one million arrays, you would then write one million methods? Same with other methods. Read about object programming and change your code. It should be more like that, I added some improvements, but much more could be done, with changing those tables from static, delete some typos from your code, and move printing messages from you methods into main.

```
package some_code_from_stackovrflw;

import java.util.Random;

public class Main {
    static int[][] tab_1 = new int[10][10];
    static int[][] tab_2 = new int[10][10];
    static int[][] tab_wyniki = new int[10][10];
    static int[][] tab_1_sum = new int[10][10];
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        wypelnij_tablice(1000, tab_1);
        wypelnij_tablice(1000, tab_2);
        System.out.println("Tablica 1");
        wyswietl_tablice(tab_1);
        System.out.println("Tablica 2");
        wyswietl_tablice(tab_2);
        tab_wyniki = sumuj_tablice(tab_1, tab_2);
        wyswietl_sume_tabli();
        suma_tabeli_1();
        wys_sum_tab_1();
    }

static void wypelnij_tablice(int zakres, int[][] table) {
    Random r = new Random();
    for (int wiersz = 0; wiersz < 10; wiersz++) {
        for (int kolumna = 0; kolumna < 10; kolumna++) {
            table[wiersz][kolumna] = r.nextInt(zakres);
        }
    }
}

static void wyswietl_tablice(int[][] table) {
    for (int wiersz = 0; wiersz < 10; wiersz++) {
        for (int kolumna = 0; kolumna < 10; kolumna++) {
            System.out.print(table[wiersz][kolumna] + " , ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

static int[][] sumuj_tablice(int[][] table1, int[][] table2) {
    int [][] tab_wyniki = new int[10][10];
    for (int wiersz = 0; wiersz < 10; wiersz++) {
        for (int kolumna = 0; kolumna < 10; kolumna++) {
            tab_wyniki[wiersz][kolumna] = table1[wiersz][kolumna] + table2[wiersz][kolumna];
        }
    }
    return tab_wyniki;
}

static void wyswietl_sume_tabli() {
    System.out.println("suma tablic");
    for (int wiersz = 0; wiersz < 10; wiersz++) {
        for (int kolumna = 0; kolumna < 10; kolumna++) {
            System.out.print(tab_wyniki[wiersz][kolumna] + " , ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

static void suma_tabeli_1() {
    for (int wiersz = 0; wiersz < 10; wiersz++) {
        for (int kolumna = 0; kolumna < 10; kolumna++) {
            tab_1_sum[wiersz][kolumna] = tab_1[wiersz][kolumna];
        }
    }
}

static void wys_sum_tab_1() {
    System.out.println("suma tabeli 1");
    for (int wiersz = 0; wiersz < 10; wiersz++) {
        for (int kolumna = 0; kolumna < 10; kolumna++) {
            System.out.print(tab_1_sum[wiersz][kolumna] + " , ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

}

Further, in this line you literraly copy value from one table to another, and not doing anything with it:

```
tab_1_sum[wiersz][kolumna] = tab_1[wiersz][kolumna];
```

If I understand correclty, you want to do something like this:

```
tab_1_sum = tab_1_sum + tab_1[wiersz][kolumna]
```

Which will require to change type of tab_1_sum to int so it will store sum of values of  all numbers from all cells in tab_1.
Also I quite dont fully understand what you want to accomplish with that method?

```
wys_sum_tab_1()
```

Comment: well, firstly i wanted to say sorry for my really poor programming skills and knowledge, also thank you for all this explaining. With "wys_sum_tab_1()" i wanted to make a code that also can display the output of summing all the numbers in first 2-dimensional array, same thing i wanted to do with that 2nd 2-dimensional array but i noticed that i am doing it wrong so i wanted to know how to do it properly and wrote a question here, also I would be very grateful if you can help and bless me with good sources from which noob like myself can learn something.